# Is it possible to modify behavior of stepOver() in JDIStackFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, jdi

There are not many extension points available to customize the default debug behavior of Eclipse JDT (https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Findex.html). I need a way to decide based on the currently debugged class what is the next frame visited by the debugger. Is it possible at all to extends the default Java debugger in that way? Are there any examples?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't supported.

If you look at where the `JDIStackFrame` constructor is used there is no way to use any other class.

Comment: Thanks. By looking at the code it might be possible I guess, but of course one would have to implement all other classes before the StackFrame itself is created. All those classes aren't final so it might be possible, but is of course probably a pain :)